# Number automatically getting converted to date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an address in a cell in excel cell. When I pull the field using left(cell,4) in excel it automatically converts it to date and gives me `44142` whereas I want the output as `7-11`.

```
7-11 ROMEO DR
```

I want the actual value. Also, I have list of 30k addresses for which I want to run the formula. How can I solve it?

Comment: What version of excel are you running?  Normally when the left function is used, the result is a text value unless it is run through some other math operation after words. ie. LEFT(A3,4)+0 would convert any numbers as text into an actual number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to replicate your issue. But you can add a single quote in your formula to get it treated as a text like below:

```
="'" & left(cell,4)
```